# Can we rearrange the alternating harmonic series and make it equal to arbitrary real number?

Tags: summability-theory

By "Riemann Rearrangement Theorem", we can rearrange the conditionally convergence series and make it equal to arbitrary value.

And Riemann showed that rearranging the alternating harmonic series by $ {1 \over 2} \ln(2) $.

But I wondered what specific way to rearrange the certain series by arbitrary value.

such as:

$$ 1 - {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 3} - {1 \over 4} + \cdots \text{ → (Rearrange)} = N, $$
$$ \text{where } N \text{ is arbitrary real number} $$

Is there a specific way?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: [Riemann_series_theorem#Existence_of_a_rearrangement_that_sums_to_any_positive_real_M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Existence_of_a_rearrangement_that_sums_to_any_positive_real_M)

Answer (score 4):

You have
$$
1 + \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 5 + \frac 1 7 + \cdots = +\infty
$$
$$
-\frac 1 2 - \frac 1 4 - \frac 1 6 - \frac 1 8 - \cdots = -\infty
$$
Suppose I want a rearrangement that makes the sum equal to $10.$

Keep adding up odd terms until the sum exceeds $10.$ Then add one even term so that the sum is less than $10.$ Then keep adding up odd terms until the sum exceeds $10.$ Then add one even term so that the sum is less than $10.$ Then keep adding up odd terms until the sum exceeds $10.$ Then add one even term so that the sum is less than $10.$ And so on.

This will converge to $10.$

Comment: Quick comment: This is also exactly the/one proof of the rearrangement theorem.